# unhandled graphql subscription error - when there is no internet connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

Get real-time data using aws-appsync. But when I close the emulator's internet connection, I get an error like this. I did a lot of research, but I couldn't. I'm waiting for your help. I translated this article into English with google translation.

```
const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
  url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
  region: appSyncConfig.region,
  auth: {
    type: appSyncConfig.authType,
    apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey,
  },
  offlineConfig : {
    callback : ( err ) => {
      if (err) {
        console.warn('error');
     } 
   },
 },DisableOffline: false
},);



export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { name: "", link: "" ,veri:[],loading:false};

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    client.onConnectionLost = ({ errorCode, ...args }) => { 
  if (errorCode !== 0) { 
     console.warn('error1');
  } 
  else
  {
    console.warn('error2');
  }  
}; 
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Rehydrated>   
         <Appy />
      </Rehydrated>
    </ApolloProvider>      

    )
  }
}
```

Other Files

```
const ListAppps = gql`query listAppps {
  listAppps {
    items {
      id
      name
      link
      __typename
    }
  }
}`;   

  const OnCreateAppp = gql`subscription onCreateAppp {
    onCreateAppp {
      id
      name
      link
    }
  }`;    


class Appy extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.data.subscribeToMore(
      buildSubscription(OnCreateAppp, ListAppps)
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {
          this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
            <Text key={index}>{JSON.stringify(post.name)}</Text>
          ))
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(ListAppps, {
  options: {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
  },
  props: props => ({
    posts: props.data ? props.data.listAppps.items : [],
    data: props.data
  }),
})(Appy)
```

[image]

Comment: How did you solve this error ?